# Process a lot of data without waiting for a chunk to finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am confused with `map`, `imap`, `apply_async`, `apply`, `Process` etc from the `multiprocessing` python package.

What I would like to do:

I have **100 simulation script files** that need to be run through a simulation program. I would like python to run as many as it can in parallel, then **as soon as one is finished, grab a new script and run that one**. I don't want any waiting.

Here is a demo code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp  
import time

def run_sim(x):
    # run 
    print("Running Sim: ", x)
    
    # artificailly wait 5s
    time.sleep(5)
    
    
    return x

def main():
    # x => my simulation files
    x = list(range(100))
    # run parralel process
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-1)
    # get results
    result = pool.map(run_sim, x)

    print("Results: ", result)
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

However, I don't think that map is the correct way here since I want the PC not to wait for the batch to be finished but immediately proceed to the next simulation file.

The code will run `mp.cpu_count()-1` simulations at the same time and then wait for every one of them to be finished, before starting a new batch of size `mp.cpu_count()-1` . I don't want the code to wait, but just to grab a new simulation file as soon as possible.

[image]

**Do you have any advice on how to code it better?**

*Some clarifications:*

I am reducing the pool to one less than the CPU count because I don't want to block the PC.
I still need to do light work while the code is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works correctly using map. The trouble is simply that you sleep all thread for 5 seconds, so they all finish at the same time.

Try this code to see the effect correctly:

```
import multiprocessing as mp  
import time
import random

def run_sim(x):
    # run 
    t = random.randint(3,10)
    print("Running Sim: ", x, " - sleep ", t)
    time.sleep(t)
            
    return x

def main():
    # x => my simulation files
    x = list(range(100))
    # run parralel process
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-1)
    # get results
    result = pool.map(run_sim, x)

    print("Results: ", result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Oh, thanks... so you are saying -and it seems like it when I run your code - that `map` already grabs the next available sim, as soon as a worker is finished? Then when would you use `imap`  or `apply_async` ? Thanks

Comment: Using `apply_async` you can execute individual functions in the pool. it is non-blocking, so you have to join manually at the end. `imap` seems to be the iterator version of map and useful for "long iterables" according to the docs.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by executing "individual functions" ?

Comment: You would probably have to do something `for i in list(range(100)): pool.apply_async(run_sim, i)` to achieve the same as the `map` does for you (i.e. apply `run_sim` to each value in your list.)